# std::to_string store in const char*

Tags: c++, string

I need to convert number to string and store it into a `const char*` but problem is that `const char*` variable is blank after assignment.

In the following example code I expect to see number output converted to `const char*`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int number = 123;
    const char* ptr_num_string = std::to_string(number).c_str();
    std::cout << "number to string is: " <<  ptr_num_string << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is blank:

> number to string is:

How do I convert number into a const char* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) returns a *temporary* `std::string`.
- The pointer returned by [`std::string::c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is invalidated by any non-`const` operation on the `string` itself - this is because it basically gives you a pointer to the `string`'s internal buffer.
- Destroying a `std::string` is definitely a non-`const` operation!

Therefore, you can't expect to take a pointer into the `string` returned by `to_string` and ever be able to use that. You need to save a copy of that `string` in the first place:

```
int number = 123;
std::string const numAsString = std::to_string(number);
char const* ptrToNumString = numAsString.c_str(); // use this as long as numAsString is alive
```

---

What you are doing is called [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - this means that your program is invalid, and *anything could happen*. It could crash, it could print out some garbage, it could appear to work normally, it could do a different one of these each time you run your program...

Answer (score 1):

It is not "blank" it points to the buffer of string that went out of scope. So accessing it causes Undefined Behavior. You need to keep string alive:

```
auto str{std::to_string(number)};
auto ptr_num_string{str.c_str()};
std::cout << "number to string is: " <<  ptr_num_string << std::endl;
```